# Stream API java Comparator

Tags: java, сортировка, java-stream

```
public Catalog sortCatalog(Catalog catalog, String configPath) {

        //Тут я копирую каталог, чтобы старый не трогался
        Catalog sortedCatalog = cloneCatalog(catalog);

         //SortConfig - Это класс с двумя полями: имя поля по которому будем 
         //сортировать и порядок(asc|desc)
        List<SortConfig> sortConfig = SortService.getConfigList(configPath);

        //Каталог имеет одно поле - список катерорий. 
        //Каждая категория так же имеет список продуктов этой категории. 
        //Это обычные POJO
        for (Category category : sortedCatalog.getCategories()) {
            Stream<Product> productStream = category.getProducts().stream();

            for (SortConfig config : sortConfig) {
                productStream = productStream
                        .sorted(new CombinedProductComparator(config.getFieldName(), config.getOrder()));
               //CombinedComparator - это компаратор, который сравнивает продукты 
               //в зависимости от того, какие значения в полях имеет SortConfig 
               //(тоесть, например, сортировка по цене asc)
            }

            category.setProducts(productStream.collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
        return sortedCatalog;
    }
```

Передо мной стоит задача: в `SortConfig` настраивается по xml-конфигурации. Например:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sort-criterias>

    <name order="asc"/>
    <price order="asc"/>
    <rate order="desc"/>

</sort-criterias>
```

Мне необходимо сортировать сначала по имени, потом только цене и в конце по рейтингу. Но мой метод все поставил с ног на голову! По итогу за главный критерий сортировки он берет последнюю строчку конфигурации. Мне нужно это поправить. Я знаю, что можно корректно сортировать по `sort(Comparator.thenComparing(...).thenComparing(...))` Но не могу даже представить как! Помогите пж(( Буду безмерно благодарна

Листинг классов выше:

```
public class CombinedProductComparator implements Comparator<Product> {

    private final String fieldName;
    private final Order order;

    public CombinedProductComparator(String fieldName, Order order) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Product o1, Product o2) {

        Comparator<Product> comparator;

        switch (fieldName) {

            case "name":
                comparator = new ProductNameComparator();
                break;

            case "price":
                comparator = new ProductPriceComparator();
                break;

            default:

            case "rate":
                comparator = new ProductRateComparator();
        }

        if (order == Order.DESC) comparator = comparator.reversed();
        return comparator.compare(o1, o2);
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SortConfig {

    private String fieldName;
    private Order order;

    public SortConfig(String fieldName, Order order) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.order = order;
    }
}
```

```
public class Catalog implements Serializable {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<Category> categories;

}
```

```
@Data
public abstract class Category implements Serializable {

    protected String title;
    protected List<Product> products;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Category category = (Category) o;
        return title.equals(category.title);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(title);
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private long priceInCents;
    private int rate;

    public Product(String name, long priceInCents, int rate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.priceInCents = priceInCents;
        this.rate = rate;
    }
}
```

**Можно конечно сделать так:**

```
public Catalog sortCatalog(Catalog catalog, String configPath) {

        Catalog sortedCatalog = cloneCatalog(catalog);

        List<SortConfig> sortConfig = SortService.getConfigList(configPath);

        for (Category category : sortedCatalog.getCategories()) {

            category.setProducts(category.getProducts().stream()
                    .sorted(new CombinedProductComparator(sortConfig.get(0).getFieldName(), sortConfig.get(0).getOrder())
                    .thenComparing(new CombinedProductComparator(sortConfig.get(1).getFieldName(), sortConfig.get(1).getOrder()))
                    .thenComparing(new CombinedProductComparator(sortConfig.get(2).getFieldName(), sortConfig.get(2).getOrder())))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        }

        return sortedCatalog;
    }
```

Но что если `sort-config.xml` будет иметь переменное количество параметров сортировки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создавайте компаратор как-то так:

```
Comparator<Product> combined = null;
for(SortConfig sortConfig : SortService.getConfigList(configPath)) {
    if (combined == null) {
        combined = new CombinedProductComparator(
sortConfig.getFieldName(), sortConfig.getOrder());
    } else {
        combined = combined.thenComparing(
              new CombinedProductComparator(
                    sortConfig.getFieldName(), sortConfig.getOrder()));
    }                
}
```

Или вариант с `reduce`:

```
Comparator<Product> combined = sortService.getConfigList(configPath)
  .stream()
  .map(sortConfig -> new CombinedProductComparator(
          sortConfig.getFieldName(), sortConfig.getOrder()))
  .reduce(null, (combinedSoFar, nextComparator) -> 
     (combinedSoFar == null) ? nextComparator : combinedSoFar.thenComparing(nextComparator)
});
```

Ну и потом используйте уже составной компаратор для сортировки:

```
productStream = productStream.sorted(combined);
```

Comment: ето гениально. Спасибо! Не думала, что компаратор можно конструировать

Comment: а возможно это сделать с помощью reduce? Вместо цикла

Comment: спасибо) что-то я сама попыталась немного по-другому и словила ClassCastEx

Comment: беда(( ```thenComparing(nextComparator)``` подсвечивается красным - идея говорит что это из-за того что в стриме ```combinedSoFar``` принадлежит к ```SortConfig```

Comment: Действительно там ошибка. Поправил.

Answer (score 0):

Поправилось, получилось так:

```
List<Comparator<Product>> comparators = SortService.getConfigList(configPath)
               .stream()
               .map(s -> new CombinedProductComparator(s.getFieldName(), s.getOrder()))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());

       Comparator<Product> combinedComparator = comparators.stream()
               .reduce(null, (comp1, comp2) -> {
                   if (comp1 == null) {
                       return comp2;
                   } else {
                       return comp1.thenComparing(comp2);
                   }
               });

       Catalog sortedCatalog = cloneCatalog(catalog);

       sortedCatalog.setCategories(sortedCatalog.getCategories().stream()
               .peek(c -> c.getProducts().sort(combinedComparator))
               .collect(Collectors.toList()));
       return sortedCatalog;
```

**Спасибо @RomanKonoval!**